# PHP fetching Data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to fetch the flag field from mysql of the `$_SESSION['sess_user'`]
But I dont know it never works with me...
  **

```
$c_user=$_SESSION['sess_user'];

    $queryflag = "SELECT `flag` FROM `members` WHERE `user`='" . $c_user . "'";
    $resultflag = mysql_query($queryflag);
    echo $resultflag;
```

**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_assoc()

```
$resultflag = mysql_query($queryflag) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultflag)) {
  print_r($row)
}
```

**Please note that mysql_* functions were deprecated, you need to switch to [`PDO`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) or [`MySQLI`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysqli/info)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,

```
   $name = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
   $q = mysql_query("select flag from members where user='".$name."' ") or die(mysql_error());
   $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
   $flag = $res['flag'];
```

You can use mysql_fetch_assoc() to retrieve filed from database here.
**Reference: [here](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2014/03/php-mysql-fetch-assoc.html)**